# Каким образом inline-block элемент выравнивается в block элементе

Tags: html, css

Каким образом inline-block элемент выравнивается вертикально в block элементе, у которого указан line-height? Если line-height - высота строки, то где находится эта строка по отношению к блочному элементу, в котором она задана?

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffc;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В данном конкретном случае действует `vertical-align: baseline` https://assets.htmlacademy.ru/img/blog/94/group-1@2x.png

Comment: Но ведь базовой линией для родительского элемента будет нижний край этого элемента, поскольку line-height равен  высоте данного элемента. А этот элемент выстраивается по центру

Comment: Не будет, baseline расположен там, где находится нижняя граница букв без палочек (палка у `q` торчит ниже baseline), а это напрямую зависит от `font-size`. Увеличьте размер шрифта — квадрат поедет немного вниз

Comment: Даже не только от `font-size`, но и от `font-family`. Если выбрать специфический шрифт со специфическими палочками, квадрат тоже может немного съехать, несмотря на полное отсутствие текста в примере :)

Comment: Хорошо, inline-block выравнивается относительно базовой линии буквы, которая находится по центру родительского блока. Но каким образом она попадает в центр, а не в самый низ родительского блока, этого я понять не могу..

Comment: Текст всегда (вроде бы) выстраивается ровно по центру `line-height` и в итоге baseline оказывается чуть ниже центра. Просто допишите текст возле квадрата и всё наглядно увидите

Comment: Вот, этого знания (текст выстраивается ровно по центру `line-height`) мне и не хватало) Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: (кто-нибудь, оформите полноценный ответ, а то я в своих комментах не стопроцентно уверен и мне лень)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый потомок inline/inline-block/block элемента выравнивается так, как будто его контейнер строки(`line-box`) начинается с символа нулевой ширины (`strut`). В нашем случае `strut` имеет `line-height` 200px и базовую линию(`baseline`) приблизительно по центру родительского элемента. Относительно него дочерние строчные элементы и выравниваются.

Если хотите углубиться в эту тему: http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: Статья на русском: http://css-live.ru/css/metriki-shrifta-line-height-vertical-align.html#fn-3